# Count iteration on the Enumerable cycle

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I would like to use an enumerator like `[1,2,3].cycle` and count how many times I've gone through the iterations.  `[1,2,3].cycle.count` creates an infinite loop and doesn't bring the iteration count. I'm playing a card game, and it cycles through the players. It's easy in the game to say:

```
@round = 0
if @turn == 1
  @round += 1
end
```

and it works. But I would like to know how to change `count` or add `iter` only for enumerators with `cycle` into something like this:

```
module Enumerable
  def cycle  
    super
    def count
      puts "Hi"
    end  
  end  
end
```

Since everything in Ruby is an Object, I should be able to create functions within functions as this case works:

```
def x
  def y
    puts 1
  end
end
x.y
# => 1
```

How can I overwrite the behaviour of `count` only within a `cycle` enumerator or at least create a working method `iter` within the `cycle` Enumerator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put something like that together fairly easily. Something like

```
class Iter < Array
  attr_reader :iteration

  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args)
    @pointer = 0
    @iteration = 1 # Current iteration
  end

  def next
    self[@pointer].tap {
      @pointer = (@pointer + 1) % size
      @iteration += 1 if @pointer == 0
    }
  end
end

iter = Iter.new [1,2,3]

7.times { puts 'iteration %d: %d' % [iter.iteration, iter.next] }

# iteration 1: 1
# iteration 1: 2
# iteration 1: 3
# iteration 2: 1
# iteration 2: 2
# iteration 2: 3
# iteration 3: 1
```

Comment: This works but only when calling `Iter#iteration` before calling `Iter#next`. A method `#next_with_iteration` that returns `[self.next, iteration]` will produce unexpected results. I would suggest adding `def next_with_iteration; temp = @iteration; [self.next, temp]; end`

Answer (score 3):

Another option, which does not need to keep count of the number of calls to next:

```
class CycledArray
  def initialize(arr)
    @cycle = arr.cycle.each_with_index
    @iteration_length = arr.length
  end

  def next
    @cycle.next.first
  end

  def iterations
    @cycle.peek.last/@iteration_length
  end
end

arr = CycledArray.new([1,2,3])
56.times { arr.next }
arr.next
# => 3
arr.iterations
# => 19
```

Comment: This works.  I see the iterations start at `0` in this example.

Comment: @6ftDan - a matter of taste I guess, before making a full iteration, I would say `iterations` should be `0`...

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
ary = [1,2,3]

ary.cycle.with_index do |n,i|
  iteration_number = i / ary.size
  puts "n: #{n} iteration: #{iteration_number}"
  break if i == 10
end
```

Comment: Yours does not count iterations of the entire cycle.  But it counts the number of times it increments through the array.

Comment: Try this `[1,2,3].cycle.with_index { |n,i| break if i == 6; puts "VAL: " + String(n) + " ITER: " + String(i) }` It simply counts 1-0, 2-1, 3-2, 1-3, 2-4, 3-5

Answer (score 1):

So many ways to do this, eh? You could also subclass `Array`, create an enumerator `arr.cycle` and step through it using [Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
class CycleArr < Array
  def initialize arr
    @sz = arr.size
    @enum = arr.cycle
  end

  def next
    @count = (@count ||= 0) + 1
    @enum.next
  end

  def cycle_count
    1 + (@count - 1) % @sz
  end  
end

c = CycleArr.new(['dog', 'cat', 'pig'])
7.times { p [c.next, c.cycle_count] }
  # ["dog", 1]
  # ["cat", 2]
  # ["pig", 3]
  # ["dog", 1]
  # ["cat", 2]
  # ["pig", 3]
  # ["dog", 1]
```

Comment: `CycleArr#cycle_count` does not work as expected. `7.times { p [c.next, c.cycle_count] }` returns `["dog", 0] ["cat", 0] ["pig", 1] ["dog", 1] ["cat", 1] ["pig", 2] ["dog", 2]`

Comment: @moveson, thanks. It's curious that no one spotted that before.

Comment: It's just a timing thing. If you do `[c.cycle_count, c.next]` you get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers above contain hidden problems in the way iteration/cycle_count is returned; for example, the iteration/count_cycle may be wrong if the data is requested before the iteration is checked. A more useful method would return `[object, iteration]` (analogous to the way `#each_with_index` returns `[object, index]`) and would take a block.

Drawing from @Ursus and @7stud based on the similar question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41667699/5961578), I like this solution:

```
module Enumerable
  def each_with_iteration
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      iteration = 1
      enum = self.cycle
      loop do
        enum.peek # raises StopIteration if self.empty?
        self.size.times do
          e = [enum.next, iteration]
          y << (block_given? ? yield(e) : e)
        end
        iteration += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This makes it a close analog to `Enumerable#each_with_index`, for example:

```
>> enum = %w(dog duck sheep rabbit).each_with_iteration
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
>> 7.times { p enum.next }
["dog", 1]
["duck", 1]
["sheep", 1]
["rabbit", 1]
["dog", 2]
["duck", 2]
["sheep", 2]
=> 7
>> enum.first(7)
=> [["dog", 1],
 ["duck", 1],
 ["sheep", 1],
 ["rabbit", 1],
 ["dog", 2],
 ["duck", 2],
 ["sheep", 2]]
```

And with a block:

```
>> animals = %w(dog duck sheep rabbit)
=> ["dog", "duck", "sheep", "rabbit"]
>> enum = animals.each_with_iteration { |animal, iter| "This is #{animal} number #{iter}" }
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
>> enum.first(7)
=> ["This is dog number 1",
 "This is duck number 1",
 "This is sheep number 1",
 "This is rabbit number 1",
 "This is dog number 2",
 "This is duck number 2",
 "This is sheep number 2"]
```

This also works as expected on a Hash, Set, Range, or other Enumerable.

EDIT:

1. Added a guard to keep from entering an infinite loop if self.empty?
2. Incorporated `yield` to operate on a block.