# Enumerator consisting of a repeating (but changing) array

Tags: ruby

I have a set of objects that needs to repeat an indeterminate number of times. This would be easy enough to set up if the array were fixed:

```
>> enum = ['Start', 'Peak', 'Finish'].cycle
>> enum.first(7)
=> ['Start', 'Peak', 'Finish', 'Start', 'Peak', 'Finish', 'Start']
```

But the result I want is this:

```
>> enum = <Enumerator magic here>
>> enum.first(7)
=> ['Start Lap 1', 'Peak Lap 1', 'Finish Lap 1', 'Start Lap 2', 'Peak Lap 2', 'Finish Lap 2', 'Start Lap 3']
```

It seems like I should be able to start with `(1..Float::INFINITY)` and get the right result with `#map` or `#each`, but I'm having no luck. I know I could use `(1..arbitrary_big_number)` and make a big array, but hoping for a lazy-evaluated solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  lap = 1
  ss = %w(Start Peak Finish).cycle
  loop do
    3.times { y << "#{ss.next} Lap #{lap}" }
    lap += 1
  end
end

enum.first(7)
 => ["Start Lap 1", "Peak Lap 1", "Finish Lap 1", "Start Lap 2", "Peak Lap 2", "Finish Lap 2", "Start Lap 3"]
```

Comment: Nice answer. You can clean it up a bit and make it more general:  `loop do
    (arr_count).times do
      y << "#{cycle_e.next} #{added_word} #{lap}"
    end
    lap += 1
  end`

Comment: Done. Thanks bro ;)

Comment: (Also notifying @7stud): My question has been marked as a duplicate, but I further generalized your code and submitted it as an answer on the original question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41686275/5961578). I think it's a better solution than any of the answers on that question. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: My pleasure, Sir ;)